# Having legends inside the Chart.js canvas

Tags: chart.js

The question is straighforward but i haven't found yet a post leading to the answer. I've managed to add a legend using the `legendTemplate` and displaying it in the html, but none where i can display this legend inside the canvas.

If i want to export the graph as an image so it would be nice to have the legend embeded in the canvas ! I hope i'm not the only one thinking that.

I've seen the [generateLegend method](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#advanced-usage-prototype-methods) but it's generating html, for non canvas tags as far as i know.

EDIT ---

I've tested, sofar without success, the method of svg image in canvas

This is [my test](https://jsfiddle.net/zn6seqr8/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing Chart.js to do it, you might want to use consider using a  generic html to canvas solution to keep it flexible.

One example would be https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas

From the link above

> You can't just draw HTML into a canvas. Instead, you need to use an
>   SVG image containing the content you want to render. To draw HTML
>   content, you'd use a `<foreignObject>` element containing the HTML, then
>   draw that SVG image into your canvas.

---

Here's the adapted version of your code. I didn't change much in spirit - just moved some of the code around

Also, just a quick note that this doesn't work in IE. But I presume you just wanted Chrome based on your comments.

**Script**

```
var radarChartData = {
  labels: ["Eating", "Drinking", "Sleeping", "Designing", "Coding", "Cycling", "Running"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [65, 59, 90, 81, 56, 55, 40]
  }, {
    label: "My Second dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 96, 27, 100]
  }]
};

// legend for Chart
var legend = "<ul style=\"list-style-type:none;\">";
radarChartData.datasets.forEach(function(dataset){
  legend += "<li><div style=\"background-color:" + dataset.strokeColor + ";height:0.5em;width:0.5em;float:left;margin-top:0.5em;margin-right:0.5em;\"></div><span style='font-family:Verdana;font-size: 12px;'>";
  if (dataset.label) {
    legend += dataset.label
  }
  legend += "</span></li>";
})
legend += "</ul>";

var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
  '<foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' +
  '<div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="font-size:20px">' +
  legend +
  '</div>' +
  '</foreignObject>' +
  '</svg>';

var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
var img = new Image();
var svg = new Blob([data], {
  type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
});
var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(svg);

img.onload = function() {
  DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);

  Chart.types.Radar.extend({
    name: "RadarAlt",
    draw: function() {
      this.scale.yCenter = this.chart.width / 2;
      Chart.types.Radar.prototype.draw.apply(this, arguments);
      this.chart.ctx.drawImage(img, 0, this.chart.width);
    }
  });

  // create chart
  var ctx = document.getElementById("radaranalytics").getContext('2d');
  var radar = new Chart(ctx).RadarAlt(radarChartData, {
    responsive: true
  });
}
img.src = url;
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="radaranalytics" height="350" width="300" />
```

---

Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/zn6seqr8/6/

Comment: Tell me if i'm wrong :what you're suggesting, using the page you provide is i create a canvas, in which i create an svg image containing the Chart.js canvas + the html legend ?

Comment: Create chartjs chart, create svg element containing the legend html, create canvas and copy both into it.

Comment: ok, that's what i understood then :) I'll try that. I upvote but don"t set it to accept until i manage to so it.

Comment: Sure. If your legend template is very simple though and is going to remain simple you can just write the legend out into the chart.js using the onanimationcomplete callback.

Comment: I didn't checked out this callback. Maybe it'll be easier using it

Comment: As you stated i created the chart, the legend in a svg image. But when i put them together only one appeared. I also displayed them apart to be sure there was no error in the js. [This is the test](https://jsfiddle.net/zn6seqr8/)

Comment: I've [updated the code](https://jsfiddle.net/zn6seqr8/3/). Now i found that the legend is underneath the chart(if i remove the chart part i see the legend). How can i show both ?

Comment: awesome :) Thanks you deserve two thumbs up :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use postion equal **chartArea** to insert legend inside canvas, example:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
...
options: {
    plugins: {
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'chartArea'
        }
    }
 }
});
```